# How to create QSplitter ui class via qt designer?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I am new to Qt and I need to implement a monitoring interface with the following considerations:

1. I have a main window, on which I should put multiple screens, qsplitter appears to be the best solution.
2. The interface provides user with the option of changing the number of cameras, so `QSplitter` should be created/re-created during run time.

The problem is that I have too many cameras to pre-define widgets for them, so I need to create `QSplitter` UI instances dynamically.
The problem is that I can't find `QSplitter` classes when using `Qt Designer` and creating `QSplitter` class programatically is not working as `MainWindow` has been created through `Qt Designer` (.ui).
I would like to hear any suggestions regarding this issue, if there are better approaches, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSplitter` isn't a strict UI element, it's essentially a parent element that controls child elements. If you want to do it through Designer you'd probably run into headaches, but the basic gist is you select a number of widgets to be controlled by it, and click the `Layout Horizontally/Vertically in splitter` button which is in the layout buttons group.

What you might be best doing is creating your child elements programmatically, creating your splitter programmatically, adding the child widgets with `someSplitter->addWidget(...)`. In the Qt docs there's some sample code for this:

```
QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter(parent);
QListView *listview = new QListView;
QTreeView *treeview = new QTreeView;
QTextEdit *textedit = new QTextEdit;
splitter->addWidget(listview);
splitter->addWidget(treeview);
splitter->addWidget(textedit);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#details

And if you really want to do it in Designer there's a guide here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Splitter.php

Answer (score 3):

In Qt Designer, the `QSplitter` is not a widget, but a `Layout`.

Select the widgets you want to include in the two splitter areas, then select `Layout` from the context menu (right mouse button) - you will find two entries `Layout Horizontally in splitter` and `Layout Vertically in splitter` to group the widgets in a vertical or in a horizontal splitter.

Answer (score 1):

Image is easier to understand.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although QSplitter is a widget, you can't create one directly in Qt Designer. It is only available for laying out *pre-existing* widgets - which does not fit your use-case, since you need to create child widgets dynamically.

However, you can work around this limitation by using [widget promotion](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html). This is a simple mechanism that allows you to add substitute classes to represent widgets that are not directly available in Qt Designer. The idea is that you add a widget that is most similar to the one you actually want (e.g. a `QFrame` is most similar to `QSplitter`) and then promote that to the substitute class which you have defined in your own header file. When uic finally generates the code, it will use your substitute class instead of the class of the widget added in Qt Designer (which just acts as a placeholder).

Note that when you create your substitute class in the Promoted Widgets dialog, the base class should be a `QFrame`, not a `QSplitter`. This is because you are extending a `QFrame` (i.e. your placeholder widget), rather than a `QSplitter`. Of course, you can define your substitute class to be anything you like.